# How can I ensure a foreign key constraint doesn't exist, if I don't know whether the table exists?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, foreign-keys, drop

If I know that the table exists but I don't know whether the foreign key constraint exists, then I can do this:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS constraint_name
```

What if I don't know whether the table itself exists? I want a **single statement** that has outcomes as follows:

```
if (the table does not exist)
{
    nothing happens
}
else if (the table exists, but the foreign key constraint does not exist)
{
    nothing happens
}
else
{
    the foreign key constraint is dropped, but the table continues to exist
}
```

Comment: Dale K - No, that question is asking how to find out whether a table exists. Clearly given an answer to that question, one can piece together a solution to this problem involving IF blocks, but I do not wish to do that. I want a single statement.

Comment: It does say exactly that: "I want *a statement* that has outcomes as follows..." (emphasis added). "A statement" implies a single statement.

Comment: If the answer is that it isn't possible, then add that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as your question is concerned, and as commented by Dale K, you can't do that in a single statement.

Instead, one option is to first check [catalog table `information_schema.referential_constraints`](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/referential-constraints-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for the existence of the constraint before attempting to drop it, like:

```
if (exists (
    select 1
    from information_schema.referential_constraints 
    where constraint_name  = 'myconstraint'
))
begin
    alter table mytable drop constraint myconstraint;
end
```

If the table does not exist, then the `if` condition will not be satisfied, and the `alter table` statement will not run.

Note that you might want to add a filter on the `constraint_schema` column of `referential_constraints` (since constraints of the same name may exist in different schemas).